# Strange Duplicate importing images from iPhone to Photos

Tags: iphone, photos

I plugged my iPhone X, running iOS 14.4.2 into my recently updated Big Sur 11.6.

As normal, Photos pops up and, as I occasionally do, I wanted to import the new photos from my phone.

I browsing through my imports and this is what I saw:

[image]

Now, I like my cat as much as the next guy, but on the phone, there's only 3 actual pictures of my cat (in this sequence).

We've all heard of cats taking over the internet, but this is a but too much.

Any ideas what's happening here? How to repair it?